# Spring MVC: how to get case-insensitive ordering from Pageable

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to support case-insensitive ordering in my Spring MVC app when users click on the column headings on my web page.  When the page is rendered a Thymeleaf extension creates an anchor and the `href` is the current URL with some parameters supported by `Pageable`: i.e. `page, size and sort`.

The `sort=propertyName,ASC` format works fine, but I can't find out how to say that the sort should be case-insensitive from the URL.  I can do it in code easily enough but the standard Pageable support doesn't seem to support it.

After some debugging it appears that the standard framework `org.springframework.data.web.SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` just doesn't have any support for `org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Order.ignoreCase`.

I'm somewhat bemused about this, and am wondering if there's a good reason why?

I can look into creating my own `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` class, and make it parse `ASCI|DESCI` (to mean case-insensitive), and `ASCS|DESCS` (to mean case-sensitive) and produce the appropriate `Sort` object, but this strikes me as quite a bit of work and a serious "code smell".

I can't be the first person to stumble across this.  Does anyone have any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the only option is to implement your custom SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver. The documentation has brief guideline for this http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html

> To customize this behavior extend either SpringDataWebConfiguration or
>   the HATEOAS-enabled equivalent and override the pageableResolver() or
>   sortResolver() methods and import your customized configuration file
>   instead of using the @Enable-annotation.

For the format I would make it a comma-separated string of 3 elements: field name, direction, ignoreCase flag. Something like this:

```
sort=name,ASC,ignore
```

The last element is optional so it's possible to have:

```
sort=name,ASC
```

which would mean that ignoreCase is false.

Also it should be possible to specify only field name like:

```
sort=name
```

which would mean the default direction of ASC and ignoreCase is false.

The only issue is if you want to pass ignoreCase flag you must pass the direction which should not be a big problem I think.

Hope this helps!

Btw here is a JIRA item for this improvement https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-658 (Extend SortHandlerMethodArgument resolver to be able to detect the request for ignore-case)

Comment: Thanks for the swift response.  I didn't want to roll my own due to ignorance, but if that's the way it is then so be it.  I've implemented it to recognise "ignoreCase", and whilst I was at it I added support for "nullsFirst" and "nullsLast" too. It was a lot easier than I'd thought from a first glance.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Marcus can you share your implementation or give hints on where to start? I'm not sure where I have to put the implementation of `sortResolver()` and `pageableResolver()` to begin with.
OP of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41490340/ seems to have the same issue.

Comment: It seems a long time since I saw this code, and I'm trying to work out how I did it!  I created `PageableSortArgumentResolver`, extending `SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and registered this in my `WebMvcConfig` configuration object (extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`) and used `addArgumentResolvers` to register my class).  Your resolver is then invoked every time a request is recognised as a paging request.  Does that help?

Comment: I've stripped down the code I wrote into 5 files that I'm happy to share.  Ultimately, there's a PagingUtils class that handles both the construction of URLs (used by my paging control) and parses the URLs (used by the resolver).  Then, as usual it's just the glue that makes it all work together.  I was very new to Spring so it's probably not best practise, but might give you some pointers.  Happy to share it with the world, but don't know how :)

Answer (score 1):

If somebody is using Spring Data Commons 2.3 RC1 or later and looking for query params, use following. (Ignore case in sorting is available out of the box in Spring Data Commons 2.3 RC1 and later)

```
sort=name,ASC,ignorecase
```

Comment: Note that the "ignorecase" part of this, is really a case-insensitive constant string "ignorecase" AND NOT a boolean as I thought it was. (Had to dive in the spring code to figure this out...)